# ruby on rails group by with null values problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an hour table in witch I store user time tracking information,
the table consists from the following cells

```
project_id
task_id (optional can be null)
worker_id
reported_date
working_hours
```

each worker enters several records per day so generally the table is looking like this

```
id project_id  worker_id task_id   reported_date  working hours;    
== =========== ========= ========= =============  ==============
1  1           1         1         10/10/2011      4                 
2  1           1         1         10/10/2011     14                 
3  1           1                   10/10/2011      4                 
4  1           1                   10/10/2011     14
```

the task_id is not a must field so there can be times when the user is not selecting it
and their task_id cell is empty
now i need to display the data by using group by clause
so the result will be something like this:

```
project_id worker_id task_id   working hours
========== ========= ========= ==============
1          1         1         18                 
1          1                   18
```

I did  the following group by condition:

```
@group_hours = Hour.group('project_id,worker_id,task_id)').
      select('project_id, task_id ,worker_id,sum(working_hours) as 
         working_hours_sum')
```

My view looks like this

```
<% @group_hours.each do |b| %>
     <tr>
       <td><%= b.project.name if b.project %></td>
        <td><%= b.worker.First_name if b.worker %></td>
        <td><%= b.task.name if b.task %></td>
        <td class="center"><%= b.working_hours_sum %></td>
       <td></td>
     </tr>
<% end %>
```

This it is working **but only if the task_id is not null** when task id is null it present  all the records without grouping them like this

```
project_id  worker_id task_id   working hours
=========== ========= ========= ==============
1           1         1         18                 
1           1                    4            
1           1                   14
```

I will appreciate any kind of solution to this problem

Comment: dude, what kind of formatting(?) *was* that?!

Comment: just plain text with many &nbsp;

Comment: lol, i know that. see how much cleaner i've made it? (deleted 3000+ characters from your original!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using mysql you can use the COALESCE function to work with nulls, by changing the null value to something else

e.g.

```
select COALESCE(colname,0) from table where COALESCE(colname,0) > 1;
```

IFNULL() is another option

Comment: `COALESCE` is the standard SQL function for this sort of thing. AFAIK, `IFNULL` is a MySQL-ism and `NVL` the Oracle version but they all support `COALESCE` these days.

Comment: Yeah I thought was everywhere COALESCE but didn't want to say for sure, but actually it does seem to be everywhere, even sqlite